# MS Excel. Column product syntax so it returns an array instead of SUMPRODUCT

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to find the largest number in the column that results from the multiplication of two columns. Is there a way of doing this directly without having to use the C column? I would like to do it in the most compact way possible.

I want to know what exactly do I have to write in the H2 cell (marked as ???) in order to get the same result as in D2.

This image explains it better than I can.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **array formula**:

```
=MAX(A:A*B:B)
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: That did it, thanks! Another option is to use the `=LARGE(A:A*B:B;1)` as an **array formula**. It also works, with the added advantage that you have flexibility to pick the largest, the second largest... and so on.

Comment: @CalculusKnight ............... You are correct ! ................. thanks for the suggestion.